# Pagination in search ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

My pagination dont work in ***Ajax*** when it reach 10 data I can't get in next page or next data. 
I want to learn more about ajax.

Thank in advance

```
<?php
require '../conn.php';
session_start();
$output = '';
$results_per_page = 10;
$query = "SELECT * FROM client_info WHERE status='NO' && 
w_id='".$_SESSION['wid']."' ORDER BY date asc ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
$number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/10);

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
 $page = 1;
} else {
$page = $_GET['page'];
}
$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*10;
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{

$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM client_info INNER JOIN zipcodes ON 
client_info.loc_id = zipcodes.id INNER JOIN category ON 
client_info.cat_id 
= category.c_id  WHERE status='NO' && w_id='".$_SESSION['wid']."' && 
track_no LIKE '%".$search."%' OR fname LIKE '%".$search."%' && 
status='NO' 
&& w_id='".$_SESSION['wid']."' OR lname LIKE '%".$search."%' && 
status='NO' && w_id='".$_SESSION['wid']."' ORDER BY date asc LIMIT 
 ".$this_page_first_result." ,".$results_per_page."";

}
else
{
$query = "
SELECT * FROM client_info INNER JOIN zipcodes ON client_info.loc_id = 
zipcodes.id INNER JOIN category ON client_info.cat_id = category.c_id  
WHERE status='NO' && w_id='".$_SESSION['wid']."'  ORDER BY date asc LIMIT 
".$this_page_first_result." ,".$results_per_page."";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table" border="0">
                <thead class=" text-primary">
                  <th>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Name
                  </th>
                  <th>
                   Contact #
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    City
                  </th>
                   <th>
                    Plate Number
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Category
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Tracking #
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Date
                  </th>

                  <th>
                    Time
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-right">
                    Action
                  </th>

                </thead>
                <tbody>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $createDate = new DateTime($row['date']);
                $time = $row['date'];
                $strip = $createDate->format('Y-m-d');
                $time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($time));
    $output .= "<tr>
                  <form method='POST' action='spam.php? 
  id=".$row['client_id']."'>

                    <td><input name = 'checkbox[]' type='checkbox'   
 value='".$row['client_id']."'>
                    <input name ='do' type='hidden'   ></td>
                    <td><a href='compute.php? 
  cid=".$row['client_id']."'>".$row['fname']." ".$row['lname']."</a></td>
                    <td>".$row['mobile']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['major_area'].",".$row['city']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['plate_no']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['c_name']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['track_no']."</td>
                    <td>".$strip."</td>
                    <td>".$time."</td>
                    <td class='text-right'><a href='spam.php? 
  done1=".$row['client_id']."' class='btn btn-success' >DONE</a>
                    <a href='spam.php?spam1=".$row['client_id']."' 
 class='btn btn-danger' >SPAM</a></td>
                  <tr>"

    ;
}

echo $output."<tr>

                    <td colspan='9'><hr 
 style='height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;''></td>
                    <td  class='text-right'><input href='#' class='btn 
 btn-success' id='done' name='done' type='submit' value='Done'><input 
 href='#' class='btn btn-danger' id='spam' name='spam' type='submit' 
 value='Spam'></td>
                  </form>
                  </tr>
                   <tr>

                      <td colspan='10'>
                       <nav aria-label='Page navigation example'>
                               <ul class='pagination'>";
        for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {

                      echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' 
 href='dashboard.php?page=" . $page . "'>".$page."</a></li>";
                      }              


     echo"                           </ul>
                        </nav>
                     </td>
                    </tr>";
}
else
{
echo 'Data Not Found';
}
?>
```

I'm newbie in Ajax I try everything I work on it almost 6hours and I still dont know what to do the search is fine in Ajax my only problem is the pagination.

Here's the UI [image]

Here is the Ajax code in dashboard.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
load_data();
 function load_data(query)
 {
$.ajax({
  url:"fetch.php",
  method:"post",
  data:{query:query},
  success:function(data)
  {
    $('#result').html(data);
  }
  });
  }

  $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
  load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
  load_data();      
  }
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: im not sure where's the part where you say its ajax, there's no JS code in your post

Comment: my advice though, at the very least if you want to utilize an ajax request, separate the PHP code that does the process of making connection to database, queries and stuff and just return / echo a json string, then your front end code uses that response to create the markup based on the response, so finally: front end makes a request, either via GET query strings or POST data, server handles the request based on inputs, then server returns the response, back to frontend renders the html, the whole nine yards

Comment: I update my question sorry  <div id="result"></div> this is where I put the echo